# Ant design Table didnt hide when overflow:hidden on mobile

Tags: reactjs, html-table, antd

Ant design Table didnt hide when overflow:hidden on mobile. My table have overflow:auto auto; because I need scroll on X,Y.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xne3y.png)

Tried adding parent (all divs used overflow:hidden,didnt work) div overflow:hidden

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.